# Java Parallel Processing on cluster systems (cluster computing)

Tags: java, cluster-computing

I am developing a web-based application to provide some services. This is a scientific application which performs some processing on data uploaded by users. The methods corresponds to this processing actions are written in Java and they are completely *independent*. Obviously, the data of the different users are also independent.

I'm looking for a technique to scale this computation on a cluster like MPI in C. I'm searching for the same tool in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess setup a HADOOP cluster requires substantial effort, isn't it?

Comment: There are companies (such as Cloudera) that package up hadoop software for (relatively) easy deployment on EC2.  But yes, there is a bit of a learning curve for both using hadoop and managing your clusters.  I do not know how it compares to GridGain, as I've never used the latter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a lot of solutions to scale computings with Java, but the one I prefer, and which has the most straighforward code to begin is [Gridgain](http://www.gridgain.org)

You can have a try with [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com) which is a data-grid, techniquely, but can be used for remote execution and parallelisation of action on a cluster

If you're searching explicitely for MPI implementation, you should have a look to [MPJ](http://mpj-express.org/)